# Wordpress custom template doesn't show up for the rest of the world

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am trying to add a custom php page to my wordpress site. this page should be in plain text (no theme or other wordpress b*ullsh*t). So i created a new template in my theme folder, created a new page from wp administration page. Everything worked perfect. But when i logout and try to access to this page, it shows me just an empty wp template with no content in it. I checked that i made the page public.

what's wrong? why is wp showing two different pages for admins and the rest of the world ???

Comment: Do you have any caching plug-ins installed? That seems to be the most common cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid but the answer is very simple: the theme folder for admin and other users were actually different.